# wav file to flac not working

Tags: java, audio, wav, flac

we are trying to use javaFlacEncoder to convert a wav file to flac.

the call succeed and created a file. but the file has no audio content at all.

code is very simple as :

```
val flacEncoder = new FLAC_FileEncoder()
val path = Paths.get(wavPath)
val outputFile = File.createTempFile("talkingbirdTemp", ".flac")

val status = flacEncoder.encode(path.toFile, outputFile)
if (status != Status.FULL_ENCODE) {
  outputFile.delete
  throw new RuntimeException("FLAC conversion failed with: " + status)
}
```

the wav file sample rate is 22050. the generated file has no valid audio signal at all.

anything we've done wrong?